# Sending a one-way message with Python on all threads except the sender

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm developing an application in Python which needs to send a one-way message to all threads (threading module in Python2) in an array, except the current thread. I have tried variables, but that would result in all threads responding to it instead of all but the sender.

What is the best way to send messages that way?

Answer (score 2):

Why not make the "message" be a tuple of `(thread_id, 'message')`, and then send it to all threads - the thread that sent it can just ignore messages with its own `thread_id`.

Comment: But how to get the thread's ID from within the thread itself?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.ident, or pass them as part of the thread's initialization.

Comment: I'm having another issue with sending parameters through the initialization though, I don't know which parameters are being sent to the thread's def. If I send args=("hello") to the initializer with the def having a p parameter which is printed, it TypeErrors that the def takes 5 parameters instead of 1.

Comment: That's because you need to write `args=("hello",)` (note the comma) - otherwise, it gets sent as `args=("hello")` which is equivalent to `args="hello"`, which gets interpreted as a sequence `args=('h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o')`.

Answer (score 1):

This is what Queue's are for.  Give each thread a Queue, and write into all but your own.

Comment: If you're always notifying every thread except the current, it's much more efficient to have a shared event log that all of the threads iterate through (and just ignore any of their own messages).